# Time schedule for smart house algorithm

Tags: algorithm, scheduled-tasks

Imagine we have a smart-house and want power up devices in a way to spent less money on electricity.
For every device we know how many hours it should work(continuously) and amount of energy consumed. We assume that each device fulfills one continuous cycle every day.
Moreover we have the maximum amount of electricity that can be consumed in every hour (as a sum of electricity consumed each power up device right now).
Finally we have a cost of electricity for every hour.
Why is the best algorithm for minimizing the money spent on electricity? 
Would like to hear any ideas.

Comment: This is an optimization problem, look into the knapsack problem to get some ideas.

Comment: @user1373164, I know that it's discrete optimization problem. My first idea was that it's may related to knapsack actually, but I didn't find something useful.
However I think it strongly related to Job shop scheduling problem